# Deserlize JavaScriptSerialized string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to pass a 2D array to a JavaScript function. I have used the following code to Serialize the array

`JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();`

`string cellsString = serializer.Serialize(cells);`

I need to deserialize this cellsString string back to a 2D array in JavaScripts.

Comment: Use `serializer.Deserialize`. Are you having any problems with it?

Comment: This code is written in C#. I need to pass this cellsString to a javascript function. Can i use serializer.Deserialize thr?

Comment: Ah, got it. You can use `JSON.parse` in JavaScript for that.

Comment: use JSON.Parse in JS function